# Is this speed up normal for multipprocessing starmap?

Tags: python, multithreading

Code:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from itertools import repeat
import timeit
import multiprocessing

def add_one(number, flag):

    new_number = None
    if flag=="a":
        new_number = number+1

    return (number, new_number)

numbers = list(range(10000000))
pool = Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count())

for i in range(3):
    print(i)
    start_time = timeit.default_timer()
    flag = "a"
    new_numbers = pool.starmap(add_one, zip(numbers, repeat(flag)))
    print('time taken: ', timeit.default_timer() - start_time)
```

The pool count configurations are 3, 1 and multiprocessing.cpu_count() respectively. And they time taken are below:

```
(base) ins-MacBook-Pro-2 graph_test % python test.py
0
time taken:  7.543301321
1
time taken:  7.8004514
2
time taken:  7.892797112
ins-MacBook-Pro-2 graph_test % python test.py
0
time taken:  11.030308790000001
1
time taken:  11.616422934
2
time taken:  11.846459496999998
ins-MacBook-Pro-2 graph_test % python test.py
0
time taken:  6.376773281
1
time taken:  6.876658618999999
2
time taken:  6.518348029
```

My Mac has 8 cores. It doesn't seem to speed up a lot. Is my way of using starmap correct?

Comment: Your workload is tiny compared to the overhead of creating a process.

Comment: @KlausD., on the right track, but wrong details. All the processes were created just once, when `Pool()` was executed. It's the many overheads of _using_ those processes - not the one-time overhead of creating them - that swamp the tiny amount of work done by `add_one()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`multiprocessing` won't yield significant speedups for fine-grained parallelism - you need to do "big(ger) work" for it pay off in wall clock time.

The work done by an invocation of your `add_one()` function is simply trivial compared to the *overheads* of using multiprocessing at all. The main program, under the covers, has to pickle the arguments, send those strings over an interprocess communication mechanism; then the worker has to unpickle the arguments; then the function does a tiny amount of work to compare a string to `"a"` and possibly add 1 to an integer, then build a 2-tuple of results; then the multiprocessing machinery has to, again under the covers, pickle that 2-tuple; send the pickle back over an interprocess communication mechanism to the main program; then the main program has to unpickle the result string, and append the resulting 2-tuple to a list.

You "see" very little of the work going on to support all this, but the support work costs, in all, much more than what an invocation of `add_one()` does.

To see speedups more in line with the number of cores in use, `add_one()` needs to take more time all on its own, so there's more *potential* to do work in parallel. For example, change:

```
if flag=="a":
```

to

```
if (flag * 100000)[0] =="a":
```

No, that's not a sensible change. It's just a way to make `add_one()` consume more time so you can see that adding cores really does help then. It doesn't change the *overheads* at all, it just increases the amount of work that needs to be done *outside* of the multiprocessing implementation. Making all those useless "big strings" can - and will - be done in parallel.

Note: don't mistake "cores" for "physical CPUs". `.cpu_count()` generally returns the number of "logical" (not physical) cores. For multiprocessing, the number of physical cores is typically much more important.